# UDF, Triggers, and IF/ELSE or CASE in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, if-statement, case-statement

I have a games table, that records p1_id, p1_score, p2_id, p2_score, and winner_id.  I would like to have a trigger that uses a user defined function to automatically fill in the winner (as practice of using both).

I have the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER determine_winner 
BEFORE INSERT ON games
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE calculate_winner();
```

and the UDF:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_winner()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $d$
BEGIN
IF NEW.p1_score > NEW.p2_score THEN
  NEW.winner_id = NEW.p1_id;
END IF;

IF NEW.p1_score < NEW.p2_score THEN
  NEW.winner_id = NEW.p2_id;
END IF;

IF NEW.p1_score = NEW.p2_score THEN
 NEW.winner_id = 0;
END IF;

RETURN NEW;
END;
$d$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This works perfectly, but I don't like at all using three IF statements, but cannot get a CASE statement to work.  Many examples seem to be in different versions of SQL that do not work. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks!

Update: For reference, a ELSIF also works, which looks like:

```
IF NEW.p1_score > NEW.p2_score THEN
   NEW.winner_id = NEW.p1_id;
ELSIF NEW.p1_score < NEW.p2_score THEN
  NEW.winner_id = NEW.p2_id;
ELSE
 NEW.winner_id = 0;
END IF;
```

Comment: [`ELSIF`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN65879)

Comment: @NickBarnes Thanks!  So simple.  I'll update to just asking for a working CASE statement :)

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-case-statement/) has a function with a case.

Comment: It'd help if you included your non-working example. Just a guess, but you might be confusing the syntax of the procedural [case statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN65945) with the SQL [case expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE).

Comment: @LukStorms Thanks, that looks like an amazing resource that has turned up in none of my searches so far!

Comment: @dominicfraser Good that it helped. :)  But personally I would stick to the IF .. ELSIF .. syntax in this case.  And use CASE only for selects.

Comment: @dominicfraser Well, CASE is more usefull in a procedure when you use it like a switch. F.e. `CASE value WHEN 1 THEN x='A'; WHEN 2 THEN x='B'; ELSE x='C'; END CASE;`